# Fail to run X based applications in different terminals on one SSH session?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I am using Bitvise SSH Client 6.23 on a win8.1 laptop to connect to a server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Xming is used and X11Forwarding is turned on.

For single terminal, everything works well

And there is a feature in Bitvise SSH Client that I can open two terminal with one ssh session. When I log into the **term1**, I get:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

New release '14.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Tue Mar  3 23:38:09 2015 from 192.168.1.111
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ env|grep -i ssh
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.111 64815 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.111 64815 192.168.1.130 22
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ env|grep -i disp
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ xeyes
^C
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$
```

It works well, Then I opened another terminal: **term2:**

```
Last login: Wed Mar  4 00:00:41 2015 from 192.168.1.111
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ env|grep -i ssh
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.111 64815 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/4
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.111 64815 192.168.1.130 22
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ env|grep -i disp
DISPLAY=localhost:11.0
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ xeyes
Incorrect authorization cookie.
^C
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$
```

No eyes come out, and here is the log of Bitvise SSH Client

```
23:58:47.185 Bitvise SSH Client 6.23, a fully featured SSH2 client.
Copyright (C) 2000-2015 by Bitvise Limited.
23:58:47.185 Visit www.bitvise.com for latest information about our SSH2 products.
23:58:47.185 Run 'BvSsh -help' to learn the supported command-line parameters.
23:58:47.786 Loading last used profile 'D:\User\MyDoc\wei.bscp'.
23:58:47.789 Last used profile loaded successfully.
23:58:52.401 Started a new SSH2 session.
23:58:52.409 Connecting to SSH2 server 192.168.1.130:22.
23:58:52.409 Connection established.
23:58:52.420 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
23:58:52.428 First key exchange started.
23:58:52.526 Received a new host key from the server. Algorithm: ECDSA/nistp256, size: 256 bits, MD5 fingerprint: ee:67:a3:77:4d:3b:5e:d4:60:51:0e:e3:ef:2c:00:5a, Bubble-Babble: xicoc-hilor-gugyc-bavar-vaget-nysys-kuvip-kosov-bykaf-dohor-suxax.
23:58:52.557 First key exchange completed using ecdh-sha2/nistp521. Session encryption: aes256-ctr, MAC: hmac-sha2-256, compression: none.
23:58:52.564 Attempting password authentication.
23:58:57.700 Authentication completed.
23:59:08.868 Enabled X11 forwarding to 127.0.0.1:6000.
23:59:08.875 Terminal channel opened.
23:59:08.875 Terminal channel: X11 forwarding accepted.
23:59:12.211 Terminal channel opened.
23:59:12.221 Terminal channel: X11 forwarding accepted.
23:59:55.778 Opened channel for X11 forwarding from 127.0.0.1:50442 to 127.0.0.1:6000.
00:00:01.138 Opened channel for X11 forwarding from 127.0.0.1:53486 to 127.0.0.1:6000.
00:00:01.146 X11 authentication failed forX11 forwarding from 127.0.0.1:53486 to 127.0.0.1:6000.
00:00:01.147 Closed channel for X11 forwarding from 127.0.0.1:53486 to 127.0.0.1:6000. Bytes sent: 40, received: 48.
00:00:08.779 Closed channel for X11 forwarding from 127.0.0.1:50442 to 127.0.0.1:6000. Bytes sent: 4308, received: 4820.
```

I tried to close term1, and X11 forwarding still does not working in term2.
I also tried close term1 and term2, and open term3. xeyes Fails:
**term3:**

```
Last login: Wed Mar  4 00:07:56 2015 from 192.168.1.111
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$ xeyes
Incorrect authorization cookie.Incorrect authorization cookie.Incorrect authorization cookie.Incorrect authorization cookie.Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
wei@wei-H8QG6:~$
```

It seems that X11Forwarding works only on the first terminal opened after the establishment of the SSH session. After that, X11Forwarding does not work in any terminal.  I can only reconnect the SSH session to make it work again.

Then I tried to create two SSH session. The xeyes works for both SSH session's 1st terminal but fails for rest terminals.

I am not sure where is the problem, the Xming X-server, Ubuntu's sshd or the Bitvise SSH Client?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few work-arounds, but none of them feels like a proper solution. The last option is maybe the easiest until the issue is fixed.

- Start a second SSH Client (you mentioned this option in your question already).
- Export the cookie from the first terminal and import it in the second: 1. In terminal one, find the display number `echo $DISPLAY` and note the `:10.0` bit, then `xauth list :10.0`. 2. add the cookie in the second terminal (`xauth add <copy-pasted-xauth>`).
- Change the display port in terminal two to match the one of terminal one. So in terminal one you would do `echo $DISPLAY` and in terminal two `setenv DISPLAY <copy-pasted-display>`.

I am not a linux guru, and have no clue if changing the value of `DISPLAY` is acceptable, but it seems to do the trick.